# ReactJS conditional rendering IF/OR

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to render an element based on a IF/OR statement?

I tried something like:

```
{!this.props.this || this.props.that && <button>Some button</button>}
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: `condition ? <component> : null`

Comment: What Josiah asid or you can run an IIFE that returns the component or JSX you want to render based on your conditional block.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
Use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
{ 
  (!this.props.this || this.props.that) ? <button /> : null
}
```

You can also use [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to render more complex elements structure without container, for example

```
{
  this.props.test ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : null
}
```

Note, that when you return *null* React treats it as nothing to render.

Comment: Note that fragments are a new feature introduced in React 16. I've been waiting for them for a while!

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to know the equivalent of

```
if (!this.props.this || this.props.that) {
  // Render the button
}
```

The reason your code doesn't work that way is because of the precedence of `&&` and `||`. The `&&` is evaluated first, but you really want the combined condition to evaluate first.

You could use a ternary as others have suggested, but all you technically need is parentheses

`{(!this.props.this || this.props.that) && <button>Some button</button>}`

That way, you don't need a redundant `null`

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) on this is pretty good. I find it cleanest to use ternary operators, which work as follows:

```
{(!this.props.this || this.props.that) ? <button>Some button</button> : null }
```

You can of course have a different component render if false instead of just `null`.